# How add headers after basic auth, can't login, site doesn't loads

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, basic-authentication, request-headers

I used selenium 4, python, chrome.
I can't login in to site which requires basic auth

Hello!

I can't login if i use

```
https://log:paws@new.dev.tech
```

then site doesn't rendering and doesn't loads fully

if i trie to use following:

```
authorization = base64.b64encode("log:paws".encode("ascii")).decode("ascii")
                auth_dict = {'Authorization': f"Basic {authorization}"}
                params = ({"headers": network.Headers(auth_dict)})

                driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.enable', {})
                driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setExtraHTTPHeaders', params)
                driver.get(https://new.dev.tech)
```

then: site loads and i get cookie with token. few links like https://api.dev.tech don't load and have Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
All links like https://new.dev.tech.... has token in headers - it's correct
but links like https://api.dev.tech has empty header, without Authorization Bearer....

I understand, i should add Authorization Bearer... to header.
What i should do?